# Builtin Ice Cream Sandwich Application keyboard shortcuts question

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In previous versions of android, you could specify application keyboard shortcuts (for example, Menu+G to launch GMail, etc.) but that functionality seems to be gone from Ice Cream Sandwich.

However, there are a few that seem to be builtin, but I can't seem to customize them. They seem to be control+b for browser, control+p for people, and control+a for calculator. (Note that I'm not exactly sure which particular modifier key it is, it's just the one labeled control on my touchpad bluetooth keyboard)

Does anyone know about these or how to customize/change them?

Thanks!

Comment: is "Settings-Applications-Quick Launch" not working for you ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be there anymore in CM9

Comment: These settings are just not finished in CM9 yet